# How to add up the numeric values of character codes in python using a for loop

Tags: python, character-codes

I have my own name saved as a string under the variable name.
I want to find the character code for each character in my name and then add them all up using a for loop. This is what I've started with, no idea if it's staring about the right way

```
name = "Ashley Marie"
for index in name:
    ans = ord(index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kasra solution is the correct one, but you asked for a "for loop"...so here it is:

```
 name = "Ashley Marie"
    sum = 0
    for ch in map(ord, name):
        sum += ch
    print sum
```

or

```
name = "Ashley Marie"
sum = 0
 for c in name:
    sum += ord(c)
print sum
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply the `ord` function on all of your characters and then use `sum` function to calculate the sum :

```
>>> name = "Ashley Marie"
>>> 
>>> sum(map(ord,name))
1140
```

You can also use a list comprehension to apply `ord` on your characters but when you are dealing with built-in function `map` has slightly more performance! So I suggest `map`.

Also for longest strings you can use a *[generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)* within `sum`,that doesn't create a list and can save a lots of memory:

```
sum(ord(i) for i in name)
```

Comment: Thank you. That does work but for what this is for I have to use a for loop, making things more difficult for me at the moment.